# How to use `\mathrm` with capital greek letter and `newtx` package?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, font-encodings, newtx

I have macros that use `\mathrm`. However, if the argument is a capital greek letter, `newtx` package changes the outcome to a math symbol in `T1` encoding. I do not expect `\mathrm` to do anything on capital greeks but only pass through. Is there any way to get this result from `newtx` package?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
    I want $\mathrm{\Gamma}$ to be same as $\Gamma$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make them mathord not mathalpha so they don't follow the current math alphabet:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\makeatletter
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathord}{lettersA}{0}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathord}{lettersA}{1}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathord}{lettersA}{2}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathord}{lettersA}{3}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{4}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{5}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathord}{lettersA}{6}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathord}{lettersA}{7}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{8}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{9}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathord}{lettersA}{10}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    I want this $\mathrm{\Gamma}$ to be same as $\Gamma$.
\end{document}
```